# res.render() not rendering pug file

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've set the correct view engine in my app.js file,

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

My folder directory is,

```
|-app
   |-views
       |-fileToRender.pug
|-app.js
```

I'm also 100% sure that my request is received.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('This shows up in the console.');
    res.render('fileToRender', {});
});
```

When I load the page, I get nothing. The console.log statement gets executed, but nothing shows up in the browser at all.

Comment: Get nothing means `404` or some error ? I ran above mentioned code and it worked.

Comment: Try `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

Comment: @MukeshSharma - I didn't get any error

Comment: @DenisCappelini - Tried it, nothing changes

Comment: There isn't any other errors on console that you could show us?

Comment: Is there any error in terminal or browser response, any crash or something?!

Comment: @Yahya Nope, nothing there

Comment: If this can't be replicated please consider deleting this question.  If there was a solution please post an answer.